# How to programatically set `tabFocusMode` in Monaco editor

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

I'm attempting to create a single line Monaco editor, which will exist on a larger forms page.

For accessibility reasons, I want to the tab key to not be trapped by Monaco, and rather let the browser handle tabbing to the next input field.

Internally, the `tabFocusMode` setting is what controls this, but it is initialized to `false` and I can't seem to find a way to override it programatically.

The only other thing I've found is [this feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/3088) for the same thing

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same thing and found a "hacky" solution which uses the internal API. It works with the current version of Monaco (0.34.1).

```
import { TabFocus } from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/browser/config/tabFocus.js';

TabFocus.setTabFocusMode(true);
```

Keep in mind that `TabFocus` is a singleton, so this setting will affect all your Monaco Editor instances. I ended up setting it in the `editor.onDidFocusEditorWidget(() => {});` event.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I ended up writing my own focus handler, but will give this a shot!

Comment: Works like a treat, and I got to delete a bunch of code, which is fantastic. Thank you!